# I want the last few dates of last month and the first few dates of next month to fill up the calendar

Tags: php, html, css

```
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numDays; $i++, $counter++) {
    $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
    $thisDay = "$year-$month-$i";
    if ($i == 1) {
        $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
        for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) {
            //lege ruimte
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
    if ($counter % 7 == 0 && $counter != 0) {
        echo"</tr><tr>";
    }
    $monthstring = $month;
    $monthlength = strlen($monthstring);
    $daystring = $i;
    $daylength = strlen($daystring);
    if($monthlength <= 1)
    {
        $monthstring = "0".$monthstring;
    }
    if($daylength <= 1){
        $daylength = "0".$daystring;
    }
    ?>
    <td <?php if ($thisDay == $selectedDate)
                          {
                              echo "class='active'";
                          } else {
                              echo "class='date'";
                          }
                          ?> height='75px' <?php if ($thisDay != $selectedDate)
                                                 { echo "onclick='date(" . $daystring . "," . $monthstring . "," . $year . ")'";}
    //voorbereiden query
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Omschrijving FROM Event WHERE Startdatum <= ? AND Einddatum >= ?;");
    //uitvoeren query
    $stmt->execute(array($thisDay, $thisDay));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $omschrijving = $row["Omschrijving"];
        if ($omschrijving != NULL) {
            echo  "bgcolor='darkgrey'";
        }
    }
        echo ">" . $i . "<br></td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
?>
</table></div><div class="col-sm-2"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

(this is the complete code that displays the dates and checks if there are events on these dates through the database. the only thing that still needs to be added is the ability to see a few dates before the current selected month and after, primarily to fill up the calendar.)

I currently have a calendar which is laid out following the days of the week (first day is Sunday, last day Monday, then a new row).

I got this to work, but now the problem is that I have an empty space between dates which makes the calendar look incomplete to me.

What I want to do is see the first few dates of next month and the last few dates of last month instead of the blank space, the above code simply counts the blank spaces that need to be there at the beginning of the month.

Is there any way I can rewrite this to display the last dates of the month before? And with that, the first dates of the month after too?

Comment: What is the value of your $numDays variable?

Comment: the amount of days in the month

Comment: there is something missing in your code... this piece only print <td> html ... can you post it all so we could help you?

Comment: You've created yourself a problem by jumping into inefective algorithm too early. 1: get (calculate) start/last day of month 2: get events from db between dates(1) 3: calculate start of first week and end of last one 4: loop all full weeks(3), and check if there's collected data(2) for current day (if in current month). You might look into [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes for that.